# String Compression using python

Tags: python, string, compression

Everything else seems to work just fine, but last character is always off by 1.
For example, if I input abcccddd, I get a1b1c3d2 but I should get a1b1c3d3.
Any hint would be much appreciated!

Prompt:
String Compression: Implement a method to perform basic string compression using the counts of repeated characters. For example, the string aabcccccaaa would become a2blc5a3. If the "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original string, your method should return the original string. You can assume the string has only uppercase and lowercase letters (a - z). Do the easy thing first. Compress the string, then compare the lengths. Be careful that you aren't repeatedly concatenating strings together, this can be very inefficient.

```
def compression(string): 
    hash = {}
    list = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string) - 1): 
        if string[i - 1] != string[i] or i == 0: 
            if string[i] != string[i + 1] or i == len(string) - 2: 
                count = count + 1
                list.append(str(string[i]))
                list.append(str(count))
                count = 0
            elif string[i] == string[i + 1]: 
                count = count + 1
        elif string[i - 1] == string[i]:
            if string[i] != string[i + 1] or i == len(string) - 2: 
                count = count + 1
                list.append(str(string[i]))
                list.append(str(count))
                count = 0
            if string[i] == string[i + 1]: 
                count = count + 1
        print(list)
    result =  "".join(list)
    if len(result) == len(string): 
        return string
    else: 
        return result
string = "abcccfffgggg"
compression(string)
```

Comment: You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Each time through the loop, save the current character in a variable. On subsequent iterations, check whether the current character is the same as that variable. If it is, increment the counter, otherwise output the counter followed by the saved character, then reset the counter to 1.

Comment: What is `hash` for?

Comment: 1) does the code really need to consider the previous *and* the next characters, in addition to the current one? 2) What should happen the first time through the loop, when there isn't a previous character? What should happen the last time through the loop, when there isn't a last character? What should happen if there is only one character? What should happen if there are no characters at all? 3) What do you expect to happen when `-1` is used as an index for the string?

Answer (score 3):

If you are up to the `itertools` module - try `groupby`:

```
s = 'bbbbaacddd' # dddeeef gg'
groups = [(label, len(list(group))) 
                  for label, group in groupby(s) if label] #

compressed = "".join("{}{}".format(label, count) for label, count in groups)

print(compressed)  #    b4a2c1d3
```

Another way to achieve it, is to use `more_itertools.run_length`.

```
>>> compressed = list(run_length.encode(s))
>>> compressed
[('b', 4), ('a', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 3)]
>>> ''.join("{}{}".format(label, count) for label, count in compressed)
'b4a2c1d3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this easier by using a dictionary and deleting the characters whenever you use them, which counts the number of characters you want to compress

```py
string = "aabccccaaaa"

output = ""
lastchar = string[0]
counts = {lastchar:1}

for i in range(1, len(string)):
    s = string[i]
    if s == lastchar:
        counts[s] += 1
    else:
        output += f"{lastchar}{counts[lastchar]}" if counts[lastchar] > 1 else lastchar
        del counts[lastchar]
        counts[s] = 1
    lastchar = s

print(output+f"{lastchar}{counts[lastchar]}" if counts[lastchar] > 1 else lastchar)
```

Comment: What’s the point of using a dict that only ever has one key? Why not just a single integer variable? Also this is bad `for i in range(1, len(string)`  when you can just use `for s in string[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Python function to perform string compression. For example, "aabcccccaaa" would become "a2b1c5a3".

```
def string_compression(s):
    result = ""
    if not s:
        return result
    char_count = 1  # Initialize character count to 1
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i - 1]:
            char_count += 1
        else:
            result += s[i - 1] + str(char_count)
            char_count = 1
    result += s[-1] + str(char_count)
    return result

print(string_compression('aabcccccaaa'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a pattern with a backreference `([a-z])\1` matching the repeating characters, and assemble the final string with counts using the length of the matches.

Then you can compare the length of the original string and the assembled string.

**Example code**

```
import re

strings = [
    "abcccddd",
    "aabcccccaaa",
    "abcd",
    "aabbccddeeffffffffffffff",
    "a"
]

def compression(s):
    res = ''.join([x.group(1) + str(len(x.group())) for x in re.finditer(r"([a-z])\1*", s, re.I)])
    return res if len(s) >= len(res) else s

for s in strings:
    print(compression(s))
```

Output

```
a1b1c3d3
a2b1c5a3
abcd
a2b2c2d2e2f14
a
```